how to create a new QsciLexer instance without subclassing QsciLexerCustom?
ive discovered these anonymous enumurators
SCLEX_CONTAINER, SCLEX_NULL, SCLEX_PYTHON, SCLEX_CPP inside QsciScintillaBase
i wanna set the above as the current lexer of the scintilla editor instance.
for implemented lexers i know i can do that by self.editor.setLexer(QsciLexerPython(self.editor)), etc. from asm, avs, bash to vhdl, xml and yaml.
but there's also unimplemented stuff over there in the enum like SCLEX_FORTH, SCLEX_ERLANG, SCLEX_GUI4CLI etc.
ive tried this
self.editor.SendScintilla(self.editor.SCI_SETLEXER, self.editor.SCLEX_ERLANG)

but it doesnt work. the python interpreter indeed parse it error-free but theres just no highlightings and foldings.
so basically my question is how to set the lexer using those enumerators without reimplementing and subclassing QsciLexerCustom, as u know, dont repeat yourself and rebuild the wheels twice.
any help 'll be appreciated!
Btw im using python 3.12 and PyQt5 Qscintilla 2.14.1 on my Windows 11 PC

TL;DR: Yes, you can.

You do not need to subclass QsciLexerCustom and define a whole lexical rules from scratch. Instead, what you are looking for is that the bare-inheriting QsciLexer subclassing.
Without other nonsense introduction let me show you whole reproductive example code first (sorry for not being a minimal one):
(From your provided code snippet I believe you are using Python so I wrote the code in Python, but the format is the same for C++):
# This defines the interface to the abstract QsciLexerAsm class.

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.Qsci import *

import platform
import sys

# For testing purposes only.
if "QsciLexerAsm" in dir():
    del QsciLexerAsm


class QsciLexerAsm(QsciLexer):

    propertyChanged = pyqtSignal(str, str)
    
    Default: int = 0
    Comment: int = 1
    Number: int = 2
    DoubleQuotedString: int = 3
    Operator: int = 4
    Identifier: int = 5
    CPUInstruction: int = 6
    FPUInstruction: int = 7
    Register: int = 8
    Directive: int = 9
    DirectiveOperand: int = 11
    BlockComment: int = 12
    SingleQuotedString: int = 13
    UnclosedString: int = 14
    ExtendedInstruction: int = 16
    CommentDirective: int = 17

    __fold_comments: bool
    __fold_compact: bool
    __comment_delimiter: str
    __fold_syntax_based: bool

    def __init__(self, parent: QObject=None) -> None:
        super(QsciLexerAsm, self).__init__(parent)
        self.__fold_comments = True
        self.__fold_compact = True
        self.__comment_delimiter = '~'
        self.__fold_syntax_based = True
    def __del__(self) -> None:
        del self
    def language(self) -> str:
        return "ASM"
    def lexer(self) -> str:
        return "asm"
    def defaultColor(self, style: int) -> QColor:
        match style:
            case QsciLexerAsm.Comment | QsciLexerAsm.BlockComment:
                return QColor(0x00, 0x7f, 0x00)
            case QsciLexerAsm.Number:
                return QColor(0x00, 0x7f, 0x7f)
            case QsciLexerAsm.DoubleQuotedString | QsciLexerAsm.SingleQuotedString:
                return QColor(0x7f, 0x00, 0x7f)
            case QsciLexerAsm.Operator | QsciLexerAsm.UnclosedString:
                return QColor(0x00, 0x00, 0x00)
            case QsciLexerAsm.CPUInstruction:
                return QColor(0x00, 0x00, 0x7f)
            case QsciLexerAsm.FPUInstruction | QsciLexerAsm.Directive | QsciLexerAsm.DirectiveOperand:
                return QColor(0x00, 0x00, 0xff)
            case QsciLexerAsm.Register:
                return QColor(0x46, 0xaa, 0x03)
            case QsciLexerAsm.ExtendedInstruction:
                return QColor(0xb0, 0x00, 0x40)
            case QsciLexerAsm.CommentDirective:
                return QColor(0x66, 0xaa, 0x00)
        return super(QsciLexerAsm, self).defaultColor(style)
    def defaultEolFill(self, style: int) -> bool:
        if style == QsciLexerAsm.UnclosedString:
            return True
        return super(QsciLexerAsm, self).defaultEolFill(style)
    def defaultFont(self, style: int) -> QFont:
        f: QFont = QFont()

        match style:
            case QsciLexerAsm.Operator | QsciLexerAsm.CPUInstruction | QsciLexerAsm.Register:
                f = super(QsciLexerAsm, self).defaultFont(style)
                f.setBold(True)

            case QsciLexerAsm.Comment | QsciLexerAsm.BlockComment:
                if platform.system() == "Windows":
                    f = QFont("Comic Sans MS", 9)
                elif platform.system() == "Darwin":
                    f = QFont("Comic Sans MS", 12)
                else:
                    f = QFont("Bitstream Vera Serif", 9)

            case _:
                f = super(QsciLexerAsm, self).defaultFont(style)

        return f
    def defaultPaper(self, style: int) -> QColor:
        if style == QsciLexerAsm.UnclosedString:
            return QColor(0xe0, 0xc0, 0xe0)
        return super(QsciLexerAsm, self).defaultPaper(style)
    def keywords(self, set_: int) -> str:
        if set_ == 1:
            return (
                "" # <- CPU instructions, replace this by copying official docs
        )

        if set_ == 2:
            return (
                "" # <- FPU instructions, replace this by copying official docs
        )

        if set_ == 3:
            return (
                "" # <- Register names, replace this by copying official docs
        )

        if set_ == 4:
            return (
                "" # <- Directives, replace this by copying official docs
        )

        if set_ == 5:
            return (
                "" # <- Directive Operands, replace this by copying official docs
        )

        if set_ == 6:
            return (
                "" # <- Extended Instructions, replace this by copying official docs
        )

        return ""
    def description(self, style: int) -> str:
        match style:
            case QsciLexerAsm.Default:
                return self.tr("Default")
            case QsciLexerAsm.Comment:
                return self.tr("Comment")
            case QsciLexerAsm.Number:
                return self.tr("Number")
            case QsciLexerAsm.DoubleQuotedString:
                return self.tr("Double-quoted string")
            case QsciLexerAsm.Operator:
                return self.tr("Operator")
            case QsciLexerAsm.Identifier:
                return self.tr("Identifier")
            case QsciLexerAsm.CPUInstruction:
                return self.tr("CPU instruction")
            case QsciLexerAsm.FPUInstruction:
                return self.tr("FPU instruction")
            case QsciLexerAsm.Register:
                return self.tr("Register")
            case QsciLexerAsm.Directive:
                return self.tr("Directive")
            case QsciLexerAsm.DirectiveOperand:
                return self.tr("Directive operand")
            case QsciLexerAsm.BlockComment:
                return self.tr("Block comment")
            case QsciLexerAsm.SingleQuotedString:
                return self.tr("Single-quoted string")
            case QsciLexerAsm.UnclosedString:
                return self.tr("Unclosed string")
            case QsciLexerAsm.ExtendedInstruction:
                return self.tr("Extended instruction")
            case QsciLexerAsm.CommentDirective:
                return self.tr("Comment directive")

        return ""
    def refreshProperties(self) -> None:
        self.__setCommentProp()
        self.__setCompactProp()
        self.__setCommentDelimiterProp()
        self.__setSyntaxBasedProp()
    def foldComments(self) -> bool:
        return self.__fold_comments
    def foldCompact(self) -> bool:
        return self.__fold_compact
    def commentDelimiter(self) -> str:
        return self.__comment_delimiter
    def foldSyntaxBased(self) -> bool:
        return self.__fold_syntax_based
    def setFoldComments(self, fold: bool) -> None:
        self.__fold_comments = fold
        self.__setCommentProp()
    def setFoldCompact(self, fold: bool) -> None:
        self.__fold_compact = fold
        self.__setCompactProp()
    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def setCommentDelimiter(self, delimiter: str) -> None:
        self.__comment_delimiter = delimiter
        self.__setDelimiterProp()
    @pyqtSlot(bool)
    def setFoldSyntaxBased(self, syntax_based: bool) -> None:
        self.__fold_syntax_based = syntax_based
        self.__setSyntaxBasedProp()
    def readProperties(self, qs: QSettings, prefix: str) -> bool:
        self.__fold_comments = bool(qs.value(prefix + "foldcomments", True))
        self.__fold_compact = bool(qs.value(prefix + "foldcompact", True))
        self.__comment_delimiter = str(qs.value(prefix + "commentdelimiter",
                str('~')))
        self.__fold_syntax_based = bool(qs.value(prefix + "foldsyntaxbased", True))

        return True
    def writeProperties(self, qs: QSettings, prefix: str) -> bool:
        qs.setValue(prefix + "foldcomments", self.__fold_comments)
        qs.setValue(prefix + "foldcompact", self.__fold_compact)
        qs.setValue(prefix + "commentdelimiter", self.__comment_delimiter)
        qs.setValue(prefix + "foldsyntaxbased", self.__fold_syntax_based)

        return True

    def __setCommentProp(self):
        self.propertyChanged.emit("fold.asm.comment.multiline",
                ("1" if self.__fold_comments else 0))

    def __setCompactProp(self):
        self.propertyChanged.emit("fold.compact", ("1" if self.__fold_compact else 0))

    def __setCommentDelimiterProp(self):
        self.propertyChanged.emit("lexer.asm.comment.delimiter",
                self.__comment_delimiter)

    def __setSyntaxBasedProp(self):
        self.propertyChanged.emit("fold.asm.syntax.based",
                ("1" if self.__fold_syntax_based else 0))


# Example
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app: QApplication = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w: QsciScintilla = QsciScintilla()
    lexer: QsciLexerAsm = QsciLexerAsm(w)
    w.setLexer(lexer)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

I have only had the Asm custom workaround lexer implementation, but hearing you that you're using QScintilla 2.14 I'm sorry that it's implemented so I cannot provide you a good example, as it is already implemented. But the logic is the same.
The result should looks like (after you had inserted all sorts of keywords and built-in identifiers, of course):

Running on Windows 11, using Python 3.12 as you mentioned. Looks identical as the official lexer isn't it?
Explanation
Let's take a closer look. The magic that enables and empowers this workaround method lies here:
    def lexer(self) -> str:
        return "asm"

The editor reads the lexical identifier and sets the internal lexers correspondingly, and it's the only way to adopt a lexer on an editor. I guess that's why your tried code doesn't work as those enumerators are reserved for internal use only. And that's also the reason why it's a must to reimplement this method after you had inherited the QsciLexer abstract class.
Might you ask, what's the identifier for those lexers, for example Baan, Gui4Cli, etc.?
They are defined in the /scintilla/include/SciLexer.h header. Since it's a pure C++ file, you may not be able to find it in the Python package. So you need to navigate to here to take a closer look.
As you can see, there are enumerators, just like what you mentioned, from line 17, SCLEX_CONTAINER, SCLEX_NULL, SCLEX_PYTHON, SCLEX_CPP, SCLEX_HTML, etc., till SCLEX_AUTOMATIC, line 142. The name of the enumerator is, without an exception, the identifier of the lexer and must be returned by the QsciLexer.lexer() -> str or const char *QsciLexer::lexer() overriden method.
Token types
For example, Default, Comment, UnclosedString in QsciLexerCPP; CPUInstruction in QsciLexerAsm, etc. You can also find it in SciLexer.h, from line 143 onward, with the macro (, or the identifier after #define) starts with SCE_. The name following is almost the same as the lexer identifier that is returned by lexer(), but there are some special conventions:

Legend: Convention = "lexer identifier"
P = "python"
C = "cpp" or "cppnocase"
H = "html"
HJ = "html"'s JavaScript section
HJA = "html"'s ASP JavaScript section
HB = "html"'s VB Script section
HBA = "html"'s ASP VB Script section
HP = "html"'s Python section
HPA = "html"'s ASP Python section
HPHP = "html"'s PHP section
PL = "perl"
RB = "ruby"
B = "basic"
PROPS = "properties"
L = "latex"
Err = "errorlist"

etc.
Properties read/write
For example, setSmartHighlighting(bool) in QsciLexerPascal.
You can done this by creating three methods at a time: set...(), ...() and private __set...Prop(); as well as overriding the readProperties() and writeProperties() method, as shown above in the code.
The set...Prop()'s property string (e.g. "fold.asm.syntax.based" in __setSyntaxBasedProp()) can be found in each lexer file. For example, in QsciLexerBasic (imagination) you can have (imaginative):
    @pyqtSlot(bool)
    def setBasicExplicitComment(self, explicit: bool) -> None:
        self.__basic_explicit_comment = explicit
        self.__setExplicitCommentProp()
    def basicExplicitComment(self) -> bool:
        return self.__basic_explicit_comment
    def __setExplicitCommentProp(self) -> None:
        self.propertyChanged.emit("fold.basic.comment.explicit", ("1" if self.__basic_explicit_comment else "0")

Source: here
Remember, you need to define the propertyChanged = pyqtSignal(str, str) signal as class attribute (don't define it in __init__!) and the value for bool in native Scintilla is str-value "1" for True and "0" for False rather than bool or the implicit 1 or 0!
If you have anything you don't understand, don't hesitate and comment me down below.

The big problem with this is that there are quite a few virtual methods of the QSciLexer class (e.g. braceStyle, caseSensitive, blockXXX and autoCompletionXXX) that aren't public in PyQt. This means it isn't possible to (re-)implement all the functionality that the QsciScintilla class has to offer. For some simple lexers this may not matter too much, but if you want a complete (re-)implementation, subclassing QsciLexer simply isn't enough (in PyQt, anyway).

Yeah, but... braceStyle, caseSensitive, blockStart, autoCompletionWordSeparator are all public: or protected: members that both QsciScintilla and the programmar be able to access...

What's more if you wish to access those private members you can adopt the C++'s polymorphic system - that is, to reimplement everything twice under the private: section, or even public:, just like what have I done to propertyChanged(str,str) signal above.

Let's take a glance at a more extreme example: you can always add QT += gui-private to your QMake project file. And then while you're subclassing a class, let say, from QTextDocument to MyTextDocument, you can subclass the QTextDocumentPrivate to MyTextDocumentPrivate. Since almost all members at QTextDocumentPrivate is public you can access all the private members of QTextDocument by reimplementing those and using the C++'s polymorphic feature by using Q_D(MyTextDocument) macro. And that's the same logic applied to QsciLexer and QsciScintilla.

C++ is totally irrelevant in this context, since my comment was specifically about PyQt.

The real issue here is that up untill v2.9 of QScintilla, those methods I mentioned weren't public in PyQt (I know, because I've had to work with systems that are limited to that version or earlier). However, as stated in the changelog for v2.10: "The previously internal methods of QsciLexer are now part of the public API and are exposed to Python". Since the OP is using v2.14, they are unaffected, but other people coming here may be using older versions, so it is still relevant.
